# bash/awk/unix detect changes in lines of csv files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a timestamp in this format:

(normal_file.csv)

```
timestamp
19/02/2002
19/02/2002
19/02/2002
19/02/2002
19/02/2002
19/02/2002
```

The dates are usually uniform, however, there are files with irregular dates pattern such as this example:

(abnormal_file.csv)

```
timestamp
19/02/2002
19/02/2003
19/02/2005
19/02/2006
```

In my directory, there are hundreds of files that consist of normal.csv and abnormal.csv.

I want to write a bash or awk script that detect the dates pattern in all files of a directory. Files with abnormal.csv should be moved automatically to a new, separate directory (let's say dir_different/).

Currently, I have tried the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir dir_different

for FILE in *.csv;

do
  # pipe 1: detect the changes in the line
  # pipe 2: print the timestamp column (first column, columns are comma-separated)
  awk '$1 != prev {print ; prev = $1}' < $FILE | awk -F , '{print $1}'
done
```

If the timestamp in a given file is normal, then only one single timestamp will be printed; but for abnormal files, multiple dates will be printed.

I am not sure how to separate the abnormal files from the normal files, and I have tried the following:

```
do
   output=$(awk 'FNR==3{print $0}' $FILE)
   echo ${output}

   if [[ ${output} =~ ([[:space:]]) ]]
   then
      mv $FILE dir_different/
   fi
done
```

Or is there an easier method to detect changes in lines and separate files that have different lines? Thank you for any suggestions :)

Comment: Have you consider using `sort -u`?

Comment: How important is it to you to get all the timestamps printed? If all you really want is the separation of files that would simplify things.

Comment: @RomeoNinov: Thank you for your comment and suggestion. `sort -u file.csv` does not work in the case because the order of the date column should be retained as they are without changing their positions. The dates are not following an order in some files...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that none of your "normal" CSV files have trailing newlines this should do the separation just fine:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p dir_different

for FILE in *.csv;
do
        if awk '{a[$1]++}END{if(length(a)<=2){exit 1}}' "$FILE" ; then
                echo mv "$FILE" dir_different
        fi
done
```

After a dry-run just get rid of the `echo` :)

Edit:
`{a[$1]++}` This bit creates an array a that gets the first field of each line as an index, and that gets incremented every time the same value is seen.

`END{if(length(a)<=2){exit 1}}`  This checks how many elements are in the array.  If there there are less than 3 (which should be the case if there's always the same date and we only get 1 header, 1 date) exit the processing with 1.

`"$FILE"` is part of the bash script, not awk, and I quoted your variable out of habit, should you ever have files w/ spaces in their names you'll see why :)

Comment: This is an amazing solution! It works just great for the problems at hand :) 

Can you explain this bit of the syntax `'{a[$1]++}END{if(length(a)<=2){exit 1}}' "$FILE"`?

Comment: Sure @doraemon, I'll edit my answer and add an explanation.

Comment: Yeah, I understand the tricky part of "$FILE" - I spent some time previously trying to understand why $FILE didn't work when saving a path with spaces as variable, even when I have enclosed the path with 'path with spaces'. I only figured out that I needed to further add double-quotes to the variable ;) 

Thank you for your excellent explanation!

Answer (score 0):

So, a "*normal*" file contains only two different lines:

```
timestamp
dd/mm/yyyy
```

Testing if a file is normal is thus as simple as:

```sh
[ $(sort -u file.csv | wc -l) -eq 2 ]
```

This leads to the following possible solution:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
mkdir -p dir_different

for FILE in *.csv;
do
        if [ $(sort -u "$FILE" | wc -l) -ne 2 ] ; then
                echo mv "$FILE" dir_different
        fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The normal file does not contain only two different lines. If you refer to the normal.csv in the first thread, the date column of a normal file should be the same for all lines. For example, in one normal.csv there are 47 lines when evaluating with `sort -u file.csv | wc -l`. The reason why it is shown as 2 because `awk '$1 != prev {print ; prev = $1}' < file.csv` checks each file and outputs only the unique line.

Comment: Does this mean that your files have more than one column? If yes you should edit your question and add this important information, I think. This would probably make your question more useful for others with similar problems.